# Expanding to something missing an argument

Tags: macros

I have a very weird behaviour where replacing something by its extension removes an error.

Here's the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathpartir}% http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\hide}[2]{
  %\str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { \\ } { Y } { N } % A1
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { \\ } {} { #2 } % A2
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\yeshide}[1]{
  \hide#1
}
\newcommand{\nohide}[1]{
  #1
}
\let\maybehide\yeshide


\begin{mathpar}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\inferrule*{
  A\\
  \maybehide{B}\\% B1
  %\hide{B}\\% B2
  C\\
  D
}{\ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{mathpar}
\end{document}

%A1B1: ! Extra }, or forgotten $.\\...im 0em \else \setbox 0 \hbox {\mpr@item {#1}}\relax \advance \mpr@tmpdi... }{\ }
%A1B2: Works.
%A2B1: Works but the \\ doesn't seem to be removed (so the premices of the rules aren't centered).
%A2B2: Works (and produces exactly the output I want)
```

The code I want is `A2B1` and the behaviour I want is `A2B2` (`A1 is the something I added while trying [and failing to] debug).

Comment: Can you be more precise about your aim?

Comment: @egreg: I have rules (`\inferrule*{premice1 \\ premice2}{conclusion}`) but some premices are kind of optional (they would be here if you treat everything systematically but you can prove a metatheorem saying you don't need them). And I want to be able to output both versions of the rule (so one where `\maybehide` is `\yeshide` and one where `\maybehide` is `\nohide`). The problem is that the trick that makes `\hide` work is to add an extra argument.

Comment: @egreg: I could use `\hide` directly instead of `\yeshide` and it would work but for some reason I made `\yeshide` and it doesn't work and I'd like to know why. It looks like the proble is due to `\hide` expecting its second argument in `\yeshide` but it's really weird because expanding `\maybehide` fixes the problem. And I would've preferred to keep `mathpartir` out of this but removing the `\inferrule*` somehow fixes the problem and makes things behave as expected...